# How to add a row specific tr data-attribute using the rails table_cloth gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the rails table_cloth gem to produce a table of users. I would like to be able to add a data-link="X" attribute to each row of the table, where X is the url to each user. The output html should look like this

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-link="/user/1"><td>NameA</td></tr>
    <tr data-link="/user/2"><td>NameB</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

The code to produce the user table in the view is currently

```
<%= simple_table_for @users.each do |t| %>
    <% t.column('name') {|u| u.name} %>
<% end %>
```

Is this possible using the table_cloth gem?